# push the values into array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I cant able to insert the new values to array. while inserting element the values are changing but not increase the key values.

I want to insert the new values into an array if the values not in array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Add Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="salary">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['salary']))
{
 $salary = array();
 $values = $_POST['salary'];
 if(!in_array($values, $salary))
{
    array_push($salary, $values);
}
print_r($salary);

}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because every time you reload the page the array is gone!

Comment: how to avoid that problem

Comment: You could use the session array `$_SESSION`

Comment: that also i was tried but i cant get that solution. can you send me the sample please

Comment: i am new to php. i was tried like this if i did any mistake kindly let me know please

Comment: if(isset($_POST['salary']))
{
 $_SESSION['salary'] = array();
 $values = $_POST['salary'];
 if(!in_array($values, $_SESSION['salary']))
 {
  array_push($_SESSION['salary'], $values);
 }
 print_r($_SESSION['salary']);
}

Comment: anyone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example how to use $_SESSION to do what you're trying to do.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['salary'])) {
    // if you don't check if it exists first
    // you will be wiping it every time you post new values
    if(!isset($_SESSION['salary'])) {
        $_SESSION['salary'] = array();
    }
    $values = $_POST['salary'];
    if(!in_array($values, $_SESSION['salary'])) {
        array_push($_SESSION['salary'], $values);
    }
    // not required but suggested
    session_write_close();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Add Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="salary">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <h3>Current values stored in salary array</h3>
    <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['salary'])) ? json_encode($_SESSION['salary']) : '[]' ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```